# Alter Query is taking a lot more time than on any other table which is larger than it in the database

Tags: mysql

We have a table in our database that is taking a lot of time to execute queries like ALTER, OPTIMIZE etc. Some times an ordinary select query is taking a long time.
The Table size is 5GB, it is a small table containing a little more than 2,00,000 rows.

```
kt_ticket_message | CREATE TABLE `kt_ticket_message`(  
`msg_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`ticket_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`messageId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`pp_group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`msg_type` enum('F','M','R','AR') DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'F: first, M: message
      by client, R: reply by staff and AR: autoresponse',
`message` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
`staff_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`staff_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`headers` text,
`from_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'From email  using header',
`to_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'To email  using header',
`reply_to_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Reply to using header',
`cc_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'CC emails using header or as when
     replied by staff',
`source` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
`ip_address` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Use to maintain revision history of 
         ticket for reporting. 0 = Open, 1 = Closed, 2 = Hold',
`test` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'testing the alter',
`test_2` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'testing again',
PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`),
KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`),
KEY `msgId` (`messageId`),
KEY `idx_comp` (`pp_group`,`status`,`created`),
KEY `testing_idx` (`msg_id`,`ticket_id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `message` (`message`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=279508 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

This is the table structure, Check it once and see if you can spot any problems.
The problem is While running the alter or optimize queries, if an insert query comes in then the query gets stopped in the middle and it leaves behind a temporary file whick starts with #SQL- .

There has no solution till now so I could only drop the database and import it from the backup again. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using? What is your alter table statement?

Comment: How have you tuned your innodb in my.cnf?

Comment: The MySQL Version is 5.6. Not only alter statement, any command that has to rebuild the table is slow. Only a single table is acting this way.

Comment: innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/data/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/data/
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
large-pages=ON
#innodb_log_arch_dir = /var/lib/mysql/
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 50M
innodb_log_file_size = 500M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50